# Anatomy of a file, interaction with java File class

Tags: java, windows, file, operating-system, low-level

I was wondering what universal components there are to a file in a typical Windows x64 architecture and which elements of a file are stored in the OS vs the file... I know there is a file path, but does the file contain that path? Does the file keep track of its own length? Do simple .txt files contain more than the data that corresponds to the text they will display?

Further, when I create a File object in java, passing it an absolute file name, is it really just a reference to a file path? How does it interact with the actual file on my machine?

Comment: Suggest you start with : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS, specifically the internals section